# Scan String Input for each testcase in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, dictionary, recursion

the objective of my question is very simple. The first input that I get from the user is **n** (number of test cases). For each test case, the program will scan a string input from the user.  And each of these strings I will process separately. 
The question here is how can I get string inputs and process them separately in C language??? The idea is similar to the dictionary concept where we can have many words which are individual arrays inside one big array.

The program I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 100
int main (){
int n; // number of testcases
char str [100];
scanf ("%d\n",&n);
for (int i =0;i <n;i++){
scanf ("%s",&str [i]);
}
getchar ();
return 0;
}
```

Can someone suggest what should be done?

The input should be something like this:

**Input 1:**

3

Shoe

Horse

House

**Input 2:**

2

Flower

Bee

here 3 and 2 are the values of **n**, the number of test cases.

Comment: Using mismatching [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) conversion sequence and argument leads to *undefined behavior*. The `"%d"` conversion is for `int` not `char`.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't actually initialize `n` which means its value will be *indeterminate* and could lead to *undefined behavior* when you use it.

Comment: And now you edited to read a string, which is better but doesn't seem correct in the context where you use `scanf`. It seems you should be reading a single `char` in the loop.

Comment: Is there any other way to scan a string ?

Comment: If you want to get a string, either use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a whole line, or use e.g. `scanf("%s", str)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the first `scanf` is to get an `int`, so it needs to be the `%d` conversion sequence

Comment: @FKEinternet Please see the edit history.

Comment: The condition here is i am supposed to use only printf and scanf

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry, missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Don't be confused between "string" in C++ , and "Character Array" in C.

Since your question is based on C language, I will be answering according to that...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){

    int n; // number of testcases
    char str [100][100] ; // many words , as individual arrays inside one big array

    scanf ("%d\n",&n);

    for (int i =0;i <n;i++){
        scanf ("%s",str[i]); // since you are taking string , not character
    }

    // Now if you want to access i'th word you can do like
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n" , str[i]);
    getchar ();
    return 0;

}
```

Now here instead of using a two-dimensional array, you can also use a one-dimensional array and separate two words by spaces, and store each word's starting position in some another array. (which is lot of implementation).

[image]

Comment: This program allows me to give just one word as input and stops after that

Comment: Please mention input data

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: Tell your input @SteffiKeranRaniJ

Comment: Have you got it right @SteffiKeranRaniJ. Coz I m getting the output.

Comment: No. I dont get the expected answer yet. Did you try the program with the sample input i have given?

Comment: Yeah I have tried and I am including the screenshot now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145671/discussion-between-astik-anand-and-steffi-keran-rani-j).

Comment: You `#define max` but then don't use it.  You have a fixed maximum value for `n` - 100 - but don't say anything about it. Using a fixed array for variably sized data is inefficient. The idea of using a one-dimensional array with spaces separating the words and another array storing pointers to the words is truly absurd - why would *anybody* create that complexity with *zero* benefit? This answer really is an example of bad coding.

Comment: @FKEinternet, It was written by her, I had forgotten to change. I did that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100        // poorly named

int n=0; // number of testcases
char** strs=0;

void releaseMemory()    // don't forget to release memory when done
{
    int counter;    // a better name

    if (strs != 0)
    {
        for (counter=0; counter<n; counter++)
        {
            if (strs[counter] != 0)
                free(strs[counter]);
        }
        free(strs);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int counter;    // a better name

    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    strs = (char**) calloc(n,sizeof(char*));
    if (strs == 0)
    {
        printf("outer allocation failed!")
        return -1;
    }
    for (counter=0; counter<n; counter++)
    {
        strs[counter] = (char*) malloc(MAX*sizeof(char));
        if (strs[counter] == 0)
        {
            printf("allocate buffer %d failed!",counter)
            releaseMemory();
            return -1;
        }
        scanf("%s",&strs[counter]);    // better hope the input is less than MAX!!
        // N.B. - this doesn't limit input to one word, use validation to handle that
    }
    getchar();

    // do whatever you need to with the data

    releaseMemory();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program shows error at 2nd line inside main (). "A value of type  void cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char**"

Comment: Another error in the same line: two few arguments in the function call

Comment: Yes, `calloc()` parameter list was incorrect, and return has to be cast.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: BTW, I use `cnt` and `ctr` for my first 2 counter names, rather than `i` and `j` - they are easier to search/replace than single-letter names, yet still short enough to type that they're not a lot more overhead in writing code.  Besides, `cnt` and `ctr` are suggestive of "counter" which makes code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all yours is not C program, as you can't declare variable inside FOR loop in C, secondly  have created a prototype using Pointer to Pointer, storing character array in matrix style datastructure, here is the code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 100
int main (){
int n,i; // number of testcases
char str [100];
char **strArray;
scanf ("%d",&n);
strArray = (char **) malloc(n);
for (i =0;i <n;i++){
(strArray)[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
scanf ("%s",(strArray)[i]);
}
for (i =0;i <n;i++){

    printf("%s\n",(strArray)[i]);
    free((strArray)[i]);
}

getchar ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The statement "you can't declare variable inside FOR loop in C" is incorrect. It has been possible to declare variables in a `for` statement since C99.

Comment: Yeah agree, its depend upon the compiler you are using! I am using Vs2010, which is not fully C99 compliant, so apologies for providing insufficient information